# How to implement event method in JNI Android imported class to XE5

Tags: android, delphi, event-handling, broadcastreceiver

I am interested in implementation of event method in imported interface of JAVA class to Delphi XE5. 
Example:

Imagine we want to use JBroadcastReceiver from Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText. There is a event method:

```
procedure onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); cdecl;
```

Method is fired if a broadcast message is received as far as I know. Do you have any idea how to implement in a my own application?

In Java code new class extending BrodcastReceiver class. But in XE5 it is not possible. I think.
So how to enforce to call my implementation of this method. In this method should be some code to do and show a notification for user.
I persued it is possible. I have found the component but I cant to download it.

http://chuacw.ath.cx/blogs/chuacw/archive/2014/02/26/delphi-ide-broadcastreceiver-plug-in-for-android.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Nobody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer by myself.

I have found some example which is not absolutely written in Delphi. There is important to write some code in Java, but it is very simple.

Look at the:

http://www.gobookee.org/ebook/auto-start-a-delphi-xe5-android-app-after-boot-danny-wind-7q6nap/

[Android background service in Delphi XE5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467360/android-background-service-in-delphi-xe5)

There is an example of BroadcastReceiver and Service also.