# Delphi XE7 + FireMonkey + Android. The application is not in the background to display notifications to the user

Tags: android, background, notifications, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am developing an APP on FireMonkey for Android that need to show notifications to the user during the day (Example: Skype, WatsAPP, facebook). But I am not able to keep this background application, when the person not using this directly. Android closes it after a few minutes my notifications are no longer shown on the phone. How to keep this application open in the background on your mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is write a background service that handles your notifications.
Brian Long posted two blog entries that I've read over before about the process. Below is a link describing it:
http://www.fmxexpress.com/create-an-android-service-with-delphi-xe5-firemonkey/

Also, here is another SO post that may prove helpful:
[Android background service in Delphi XE5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467360/android-background-service-in-delphi-xe5)